# How to disable/enable all webdav server?

Tags: marklogic

I'd like to enable/disable all webdav appservers.

Answer (score 4):

You could list all of the WebDAV servers using [`admin:group-get-webdavserver-ids()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/admin:group-get-webdavserver-ids) and then disable all of those WebDav servers with a recursive function that  disables each of the WebDav servers using [`admin:appserver-set-enabled()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/admin:appserver-set-enabled), specifying the current $config, the ID of the WebDAV server, and the boolean `fn:false()`, using the returned `$config` in subsequent recursive calls to disable the next WebDAV server until the sequence of IDs is empty, and then save the configuration at the end:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
import module namespace admin = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/admin"
          at "/MarkLogic/admin.xqy";

declare function local:disable($config, $server-ids) {
  if (fn:empty($server-ids)) then
    admin:save-configuration($config)
  else
    let $config-new := admin:appserver-set-enabled($config, fn:head($server-ids), fn:false())
    return
      local:disable($config-new, fn:tail($server-ids))
};

let $config := admin:get-configuration()
let $webdav-ids := admin:group-get-webdavserver-ids($config, admin:group-get-id($config, "Default"))
return 
  local:disable($config, $webdav-ids)
```

Answer (score 2):

Be careful with that, if you literally disable all appservers, you will have great difficulty enabling any of them again, since that would also include Admin UI, QConsole, and even Management REST api.

That said, you can use [`admin:appserver-set-enabled()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/admin:appserver-set-enabled) for that purpose, see also the example given further down.

HTH!

Comment: I'd like to disable all webdav servers.

Comment: Ah, that is a lot less risky. You can discover webdav servers using [`admin:group-get-webdavserver-ids()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/admin:group-get-webdavserver-ids), and then combine that with above..

Comment: Well! I know how to enable it..but what about disabling it ? There's no API for disabling.